# Can I sacrifice a creature before the creature spell resolves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Here is the scenario:

- I cast a [Goblin Piledriver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Piledriver).
- In response, my opponent casts the Instant [Murderous Cut](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Murderous%20Cut) to destroy it.
- In response to *that*, I cast the Instant [Collateral Damage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Collateral%20Damage) intending to sacrifice the Piledriver before it can be destroyed and thus, deal damage to my opponent.

Will the sacrifice work? i.e. Can I sacrifice Goblin Piledriver *out from under* Murderous Cut?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can, but not exactly in the way you think.

First, Goblin Piledriver has to resolve before it can be targeted with Murderous Cut.

Second, once the Murderous Cut is cast, it goes on the stack and hasn't resolved yet.

At that point, both players get priority, and you then could cast Collateral Damage. Now, what's important is that the sacrifice of Collateral Damage is a cost, which is paid as the spell is put on the stack. That means that your opponent can't target it with a spell (say, another Murderous Cut) before it gets sacrificed.

You both pass priority.

Collateral Damage does its, well, damage, then Murderous Cut tries to cut your goblin, but it isn't there anymore, so it fizzles.

Comment: Wow - that was fast! Thanks - here is a follow-up question. What if my opponent had played **Cancel** to counter the (creature) spell instead?

Comment: @JohnSatta If the creature was countered, it wouldn't be on the battlefield, so it wouldn't be able to be targeted by Murderous Cut or sacrificed to Collateral Damage

Comment: @JohnSatta You have to understand - just like instant/sorceries/etc, creature cards have to *resolve* before they enter the battlefield and can be targeted by things that don't specifically target spells.